# Creating Voronoi diagram from Adobe Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, creative-cloud, diagram

I have some artwork in Adobe Illustrator CC that I want to use to create a voronoi diagram from.

You can see what a voronoi diagram looks like here: 
[image]

[**Link**](http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/)

I would like to use the points on my paths to seed the diagram. I have found a tool that uses an old Illustrator extension called [Scriptographer](http://scriptographer.org/), unfortunately Scriptographer stopped being supported past version CS5.

I am okay with using other applications in the workflow as long as they are free or of insignificant cost (<= £15), however I must be able to export from Illustrator and not have to rebuild my artwork in them.

Does anyone know the best method for going about this? My only other option is to write my own Illustrator extension but I would rather not as I have no experience doing so and will be a significant time investment.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some decent coding ability: if you can't find anything that already exists and want to avoid Illustrator's clunky extension API, I'd try this approach: 1) save points as SVG from Illustrator, 2) put SVG in a web page, 3) use javascript to loop through each SVG element and store its x and y co-ords in an object (jQuery might make this easy), 4) output that object as JSON and use it as input for [the D3.js library](http://d3js.org/)'s [Voronoi feature](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366), 5) copy SVG output as code using Inspect Element, save, open it in Illustrator.

Comment: You can upload an SVG directly to paper.js - no need to use jQuery for parsing.  Alternatively, Inkscape has a Voronoi/Delauney diagram extension as of version 0.49.

Comment: I experimented with Delaunay triangulation in Illustrator and ultimately found it to be better to work with that sort of stuff in Processing. Illustrator scripting is poorly documented, limited in its feature set, and a lot slower, at least when I was using CS5. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this script https://fabianmoronzirfas.github.io/Illustrator-Javascript-Voronoi/. Didn't test it, but it definitely looks promising :}